# Problema com Charset utf-8

Tags: php, html, html5

Estou tendo problemas na exibição meu texto aparece errado, porém coloquei o

```
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
```

Sem sucesso, segue como está.

[image: e e]

A ESTRUTURA HTML ESTÁ ASSIM

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN'>
<html  lang="pt-br">
<head>
<title><?php echo $dadosboleto["identificacao"]; ?></title>
<!--<meta http-equiv=Content-Type content=text/html charset=ISO-8859-1>-->
<!-- HTML5 -->
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
```

NO PHP

```
<?php
 header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');

// DADOS DO BOLETO PARA O SEU CLIENTE
$dias_de_prazo_para_pagamento = 10;
$taxa_boleto = 2.95;
$data_venc = date("d/m/Y", time() + ($dias_de_prazo_para_pagamento * 86400));  // Prazo de X dias OU informe data: "13/04/2006"; 
$valor_cobrado = "1,00"; // Valor - REGRA: Sem pontos na milhar e tanto faz com "." ou "," ou com 1 ou 2 ou sem casa decimal
$valor_cobrado = str_replace(",", ".",$valor_cobrado);
$valor_boleto=number_format($valor_cobrado+$taxa_boleto, 2, ',', '');

$dadosboleto["nosso_numero"] = '12345678';  // Nosso numero - REGRA: Máximo de 8 caracteres!
$dadosboleto["numero_documento"] = '0123';  // Num do pedido ou nosso numero
$dadosboleto["data_vencimento"] = $data_venc; // Data de Vencimento do Boleto - REGRA: Formato DD/MM/AAAA
$dadosboleto["data_documento"] = date("d/m/Y"); // Data de emissão do Boleto
$dadosboleto["data_processamento"] = date("d/m/Y"); // Data de processamento do boleto (opcional)
$dadosboleto["valor_boleto"] = $valor_boleto;   // Valor do Boleto - REGRA: Com vírgula e sempre com duas casas depois da virgula

// DADOS DO SEU CLIENTE
$dadosboleto["sacado"] = "Nome do seu Cliente";
$dadosboleto["endereco1"] = "Endereço do seu Cliente";
$dadosboleto["endereco2"] = "Cidade - Estado -  CEP: 00000-000";

// INFORMACOES PARA O CLIENTE
$dadosboleto["demonstrativo1"] = "Pagamento de horário serviços prestados JCA Contadores";
$dadosboleto["demonstrativo2"] = "Mensalidade referente a honorário de serviços <br>Taxa bancária - R$ ".number_format($taxa_boleto, 2, ',', '');
$dadosboleto["demonstrativo3"] = "www.jcacontadores.com.br";
$dadosboleto["instrucoes1"] = "- Sr. Caixa, cobrar multa de 2% após o vencimento";
$dadosboleto["instrucoes2"] = "- Receber até 10 dias após o vencimento";
$dadosboleto["instrucoes3"] = "- Em caso de dúvidas entre em contato conosco: alinesouza@jcacontadores.com.br";
$dadosboleto["instrucoes4"] = "&nbsp; Emitido por https://sistemasjca.com.br";

// DADOS OPCIONAIS DE ACORDO COM O BANCO OU CLIENTE
$dadosboleto["quantidade"] = "";
$dadosboleto["valor_unitario"] = "";
$dadosboleto["aceite"] = "";        
$dadosboleto["especie"] = "R$";
$dadosboleto["especie_doc"] = "";

//DADOS FIXOS DE CONFIGURAÇÃO DO BOLETO //

// DADOS DA SUA CONTA - ITAÚ
$dadosboleto["agencia"] = "1565"; // Num da agencia, sem digito
$dadosboleto["conta"] = "13877";    // Num da conta, sem digito
$dadosboleto["conta_dv"] = "4";     // Digito do Num da conta

// DADOS PERSONALIZADOS - ITAÚ
$dadosboleto["carteira"] = "175";  // Código da Carteira: pode ser 175, 174, 104, 109, 178, ou 157

// DADOS DA EMPRESA
$dadosboleto["identificacao"] = "JCA CONTADORES";
$dadosboleto["cpf_cnpj"] = "15.249.443.0001-98";
$dadosboleto["endereco"] = "Rua Luiz Leopoldo Fernandes Pinheiro, 521 - 2º Andar,Centro, Niterói, RJ, CEP: 24030-124";
$dadosboleto["cidade_uf"] = "24030-124";
$dadosboleto["cedente"] = "JCW ASSESSORIA CONTÁBIL E SERVIÇOS LTDA ME";

// NÃO ALTERAR!
include("include/funcoes_itau.php"); 
include("include/layout_itau.php");
?>
```

Comment: Vou verificar se atende, obrigado

Comment: Realmente resolveu obrigado